# Unittest for Python logger function

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, monkeypatching

I'm trying to write a unittest for the create_logger(user defined function) which is something like this.

```
create_logger(path,file_name):
            logger = logging.getLogger()
            logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
            formatter = logging.Formatter(
                fmt="%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s",
                datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
            )

            fileHandler = logging.FileHandler(
                (f"{path}/{file_name}.log"), "w"
            )

            streamHandler = logging.StreamHandler()

            fileHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
            streamHandler.setFormatter(formatter)

            logger.addHandler(fileHandler)
            logger.addHandler(streamHandler)
        return logger
```

I've written unittest for the above methodlike this:

```
from logger import create_Logger

os.makedirs("unit_test", exist_ok=True)


class TestCreateLogger(unittest.TestCase):
 @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.logger = create_logger("unit_test", "logs")

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        if os.path.isdir("unit_test"):
            shutil.rmtree("unit_test")
        else:
            raise Exception("The directory does not exist")
        del cls.logger

    def test_log_level(self):
        
        self.logger.info("First message")
        self.logger.debug("Second message")
        with open("unit_test/logs.log", "r") as fd:
            log_msg = fd.read()
        self.assertIn("First message", log_msg)
        self.assertNotIn("Second message", log_msg)

    def test_log_level_change(self):
       
        self.logger.setLevel("DEBUG")
        self.logger.info("First message")
        self.logger.debug("Second message")
        with open("unit_test/logs.log", "r") as fd:
            log_msg = fd.read()
        self.assertIn("First message", log_msg)
        self.assertIn("Second message", log_msg)
```

The above unittests are working fine but I don't want to use file operations like (mkdir,rmdir etc.) but use mocks, patches. Since my method takes two arguments(path and file_name)  and stores the log message to the log file and prints to stdout. Can someone please help me understand how can I replace open operations with mocks/patches? Currently I'm creating a directory using mkdir and log file in that directory and removing them at the end of the test using tearDown. How can I replicate the same using mock/patches?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you are testing more than your own code here; you are testing that `FileHandler`s work as documented. What you *want* to test is that `create_logger` creates a logger that logs where you intend it to log; the `FileHandler` is just one possible definition of "where".

The only thing in `create_logger` that cares about `path` and `file_name` is the `FileHandler`. Don't create a `FileHandler` at all; pass a handler as an argument instead, and test that your newly created logger uses it.

```
def create_logger(handler):
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    formatter = logging.Formatter(
        fmt="%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s",
        datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
    )


    streamHandler = logging.StreamHandler()

    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    streamHandler.setFormatter(formatter)

    logger.addHandler(handler)
    logger.addHandler(streamHandler)

    return logger
```

Then your test can use a `StreamHandler` that writes to a `io.StringIO` object instead of disk.

```
from logger import create_Logger

os.makedirs("unit_test", exist_ok=True)


class TestCreateLogger(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.f = io.StringIO()
        self.logger = create_logger(StreamHandler(f))

    def test_log_level(self):
        self.logger.info("First message")
        self.logger.debug("Second message")
        log_msg = self.f.read()
        self.assertIn("First message", log_msg)
        self.assertNotIn("Second message", log_msg)

    def test_log_level_change(self):
        self.logger.setLevel("DEBUG")
        self.logger.info("First message")
        self.logger.debug("Second message")
        log_msg = self.f.read()
        self.assertIn("First message", log_msg)
        self.assertIn("Second message", log_msg)
```

And in production you'll pass a pre-made `FileHandler` instead of file path components.

```
...
foo = create_logger(FileHandler(f"{path}/{file_name}.log", "w"))
```

If you are concerned whether `foo` will write to the correct file, that's an *integeration* test, not a unit test, and should write to the file system. Such a function to test can be a wrapper around `create_logger` and be the one you actually use directly in production.

```
def create_file_logger(path, file_name):
    return create_logger(FileHandler(f"{path}/{file_name}", "w"))
```

(That test will be a lot simpler, though, because you can already assume that `create_logger` is working if its unit tests are passing!)

---

Keep in mind that loggers can be configured at runtime, so treat the logger configurations you'll deploy as code that needs to be tested as well.